# javascript use url as string for array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, var

I have an external .js with arrays.

```
test = [
{
    "name": "1"
}
test2 = [
{
    "name": "2"
}
];
```

Now I want to use the url to identify the name of the array.
So if someone goes on test.html he is using the test array and test2.html test2 array.

If I use

```
var queryArray = window.location.search.substring(1);
```

or

```
var queryArray = window.location.href
```

or something like this and then

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = queryArray.name;
```

it doesn't work, because he is of course looking for the array `queryArray` which one doesn't exist.
Is there a way to use the url as an identifier?

I hope you can understand the point ^^

THX for every idea !!!

Comment: related, maybe duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable

Comment: Is this thread be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters

Comment: thanks i try this two if it works i delete my post THX!!!

Comment: could you change the structure of the external .js's array?

Comment: yes i could is written by me. why ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the ability to slightly restructure the way you specify the "arrays" you might do something like this:

```js
// =============================
// Similar but a little more tidy
// This also supports file names with characters like "-" or complete url strings
// =============================
var dataItems = [
  {key : "test1", value: [{"name": "This is test 1"}]},
  {key : "test2", value: [{"name": "This is test 2"}]},
  {key : "js", value: [{"name": "This is the sandbox"}]} // This sandbox (I think)
];
// =============================

// =============================
// You migth now use the full pathname as the data item key,
// but if you wanted to use the "name" of the file you might do something like this.
// =============================
var currentFileName = location.pathname.split("/").pop().split(".html")[0];
// =============================

// =============================
// You might want to do this in several steps to handle stuff like filter returning
// no hits.
// =============================
var dataItem = dataItems.filter(function(item){ return item.key === currentFileName;})[0];
// =============================

console.log(dataItem.value[0].name);
```

Comment: this is awesome !!! exactly what i want. 
now I try to understand the specific spelling of the array. Thank you so much !